# How to list posts with disabled/closed comments, with pagination?

Tags: wp-query, loop, comments

i'm interested how to display all posts (from all categories) that have closed/disabled comments?

I have tried using the comments_open() function inside the loop, that works, i don't know how to enable pagination on it, and here's why:

wp query - here's the query that displays all posts, i set here how many per page should be displayed
     if (!comments are open) i list the posts

so, the problem here is that i want to show 10 posts per page -the loop actually goes through 10 posts, and displays any post of the given 10 that has closed comments, and then creates a second page with 10 posts and does the same etc...

I need a filter inside the loop itself, so i display 10 posts with disabled comments PER PAGE.

Pls, can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the time right now to work the code, but you'll need to use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and filter out based upon `comment_status => 'open'`.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Can you please post more details about this. I didn't find much tutorials and examples on this filter, but it seems it can do what i need :).